# Does PostgreSQL provide a way to return the number of remaining rows satisfying a condition after running a DELETE query in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`DELETE` returns the number of rows deleted as well as providing a way to act on the deleted data in the `RETURNING` clause. I'm wondering if there is a way to get the number of remaining rows satisfying a `WHERE` condition without running a second query, or if the best practice here is simply to make a second query.

Comment: You need to do the calculate with a second query.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather strange.

If the `DELETE` command wasn't interrupted, then the number of remaining rows would always be zero.

I mean, if you run

```
DELETE FROM SomeTable
WHERE <SomeCondition>
```

and this command was successfully committed, then if you try to count the remaining rows with the same condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SomeTable
WHERE <SomeCondition>
```

that would always return 0. (Obviously, if there are no concurrent processes that change the table values.)

If the `DELETE` command was interrupted, then it would roll back, then none of the rows would be deleted.

Any `DELETE` or `UPDATE` or `INSERT` command is atomic, either all of it is done, or none of it is done in RDBMS like Postgres.

---

That's why Postgres does not provide a way to return the number of remaining rows after `DELETE` - it is always 0.

---

If there are other concurrent processes that may change the table while the original `DELETE` runs, and they change the table in such a way that the original `DELETE` doesn't "see" these changes and doesn't delete them, then you should explicitly run the second `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get the latest count.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call two SQL commands. But you must do it in a single transaction. If you don't call both commands in a single transaction the second command (the select) may bring you information that not corresponds to the delete operation.

If you write:

```js
    await client.query(`DELETE FROM table1 WHERE sub_kind='A1'`);
    var remaindCount = await client.query(`SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE kind='A'`);
```

It may happen that between the two commands another process executes another SQL command that influences the result.

But if you write:

```js
    try{
        await client.query(`BEGIN TRANSACTION`);
        await client.query(`DELETE FROM table1 WHERE sub_kind='A1'`);
        var remaindCount = await client.query(`SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE kind='A'`);
        await client.query(`COMMIT`);
    }catch(err){
        await client.query('ROLLBACK');
        throw err;
    }
```

A command executed between DELETE and SELECT commands does not affect the result. That ocurrs because PostgreSQL is an ACID database.